# parse rgb into separate variables

Tags: jquery, html, colors, rgb

I have jquery getting the background color of a div like this

```
$('#divId').css("backgroundColor")
```

I want to take the r, g, and b values and set them to their own variables. If the background color was rgb(14, 233, 119) for example, I need
`var red = 14
var green = 233
var blue = 119`

I tried to accoplish this using substring, but the problem is I do not know whether the rgb colors will be 1, 2, or 3 digit numbers, so substring is problematic. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split to get an array:

```
color.split(', ')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weaLx5hd/